# kafka consumer is unable to connect to its zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api

I have kafka and zookeeper running in a standalone mode on an ec2 instance. I have a topic named dev_spark1 created on it. But when I am trying to run consumer from command line, gives me following error for command:

./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper 172.31.8.226:9092 --topic dev_spark1

```
  Exception in thread "main" org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 6000
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:880)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:98)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:84)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.connectZk(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:171)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:126)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:143)
        at kafka.consumer.Consumer$.create(ConsumerConnector.scala:94)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:145)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
```

Comment: try increasing zookeeper connection timeout property and check

Comment: Which version of kafka do you use? Also can you add DEBUG level for your logs?

Comment: I have kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1 . And I have increased the zookeeper connection timeout to 60000 from 6000 in properties file but it doesnt reflect.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the zookeeper server is accessible from the machine where you have kafka ?

Normally zookeeper listens on port 2181 and kafka listens on port 9092. In your command your trying to connect to zookeeper on 172.31.8.226 on port 9092, is that correct.

Other way to figure this out is there is, run this command on your zookeeper machine first then on the kafka machine and check if you can connect and try out zookeeper.

```
bin/zookeeper-shell.sh --zookeeper 172.31.8.226:9092
```

If you have ability to run UI, you can use [ZooInspector](http://wpcertification.blogspot.com/2016/01/how-to-use-zooinsepector.html)

Comment: zookeeper and kafka are both running on the same machine.

Comment: I am able to connect to the zookeeper shell and list all the brokers and its topics. But only kafka is not able to connect to its zookeeper.